# How to delete table rows or list items starting from a given order number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given a `<table>` with multiple rows (`<tr>`), or even a `<ul>` with multiple list items (`<li>`), how do I delete all elements (rows or list items, respectively) below the one with a given order, using jQuery?

For instance, if there are 10 rows in a table, how would I go about deleting all rows after the 3rd row?

Comment: Nothing, I don't know what to try.

Comment: And look for what? Not knowing all the methods makes for a poor start, don't you think?

Comment: checkout all the answers, hope those will help you.

Comment: A simple request to the person who down-voted my question as "not a real question":  please notice the question mark at the end of each paragraph and the clarity of the content. They might be an eye-opener.

Comment: Great you downvoted the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery('tr').slice(2).remove();
```

Comment: Fantastic! Many thanks for the tip, I didn't know I could use `slice` like this. :)

Comment: That is a rather elegant solution.

Comment: Very elegant, actually. I didn't know that jQuery had this method and apparently, you can even determine an order number interval (start,end), not just a starting order number.

Comment: @AndreiOniga .slice() is JS

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li:gt(2)').remove(); // will keep the first 3 LI
```

or also:

```
$('li').eq(2).nextAll('li').remove();
```

or:

```
$('li').eq(3).nextAll('li').andSelf().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use next all.

```
$(function(){
  $('li').click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll().remove();
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3Z2E/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li:gt(2)").remove();
```

or

```
$("tr:gt(2)").remove();
```